# gives the character points on a set of characters

Tags: php, database

I want to ask. so I take the value of the database instance I take the value price of the database, the general value eg 3000. I want to insert a character point value of 3000 into 3.000.

description:

```
$price = $row['price'];
// eg, the value of $price that is 3000
// Output to 3.000
```

how coding php to solve the problem? please help, thank you

Comment: @user1878392: still your problem is not clear..

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking, there are several tools you can use to insert a . into a string. will you always know where the . belongs (do you only want 1 number to the left of the period)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are seeking [number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php).

```
php > echo number_format(3000, 0, ',', '.');
3.000
php > echo number_format(3000000, 0, ',', '.');
3.000.000
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to decipher your question, but is [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number-format) what you're looking for?